# Subquery in the VALUES clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, insert

Here's a real-world schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Setting]
  (
     [ID]       [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
     [Module]   [NVARCHAR](400) NOT NULL,
     [Property] [NVARCHAR](400) NOT NULL,
     [Value]    [NVARCHAR](4000) NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ASC )
  )
```

And here's the `INSERT` statement I'm trying to execute:

```
INSERT INTO [Setting]
            ([ID],
             [Module],
             [Property],
             [Value])
VALUES      ((SELECT COALESCE(max(ID), 0) + 1
              FROM   [Setting]),
             N'security.catalogs.integrated.integrated',
             N'enable-integrated-authentication',
             N'true')
```

For the life of me I cannot see anything special here, yet on at least two occasions this has failed on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with the following error message:

```
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.
```

This `INSERT` statement operates on a completely empty table, no strange options were allegedly configured for SQL Server, no nothing.

How can this be happening? From my understanding of SQL Server, `max` cannot possibly return more than one row.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on 2008 and 2012 both with an empty table and subsequent inserts. I presume there is some good reason you aren't using an `IDENTITY` column here?

Answer (score 4):

Experimentally, your code worked for me on both 10.50.1600 (2008 R2 RTM) Developer and 10.0.4000 (2008 SP2) Express. However, it failed against 9.0.5057 (2005 SP4 + hotfix). So, I dug into the documentation.

The [2005 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) says this about expressions in the `VALUES` clause (emphasis mine):

> expression
>
> Is a constant, a variable, or an expression. The expression cannot contain a **SELECT or EXECUTE** statement.

while the [2008 and higher version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) looks like this:

> expression
>
> Is a constant, a variable, or an expression. The expression cannot contain an **EXECUTE** statement.

---

From this evidence, I can only assume that the server version where you're executing these queries is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have been reading you are not allowed to use subqueries in insert statements like this.  It may work when Setting is empty because it evaluates to NULL.  This is the usual way to write a query like this.

```
 insert into [Setting] ([ID], [Module], [Property], [Value])
 select coalesce(max(ID), 0) + 1, N'security.catalogs.integrated.integrated', 
    N'enable-integrated-authentication', N'true' 
 from [Setting];
```

Comment: How can `max` possibly return more than one row?

Comment: Your right.  I missed that.  I've corrected my answer above.

Comment: For clarity, `VALUES` can not be used with a query.  You either insert data with a query **or** you insert explicit values using `VALUES`.

Comment: sub queries are fine there. See the grammar for [`INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174335(v=sql.105).aspx). It allows `VALUES ( { DEFAULT | NULL | expression } [ ,...n ] ) [ ,...n ] ` where sub queries are an `expression`

Comment: Fair enough .. I was basing this on the half dozen or so pages I saw when searching.  Regardless I think the INSERT INTO SELECT is the better syntax in this case.

Comment: @KennethFisher - Unless perhaps the OP is mistaken about being on 2008 R2. Googling that error message indicates that it wasn't always allowed.

Comment: Regarding your `CROSS APPLY ... VALUES` question: You can `CROSS APPLY` `derived_table` as indicated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177634(v=sql.105).aspx). And the remarks for `derived_table` specifically indicate the [`VALUES` table constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd776382(v=sql.100).aspx) can be used